# YouTube API Services Audit - how to track its status?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Our company uses the YouTube Data API.
I received a notice that I needed to fill out an audit form.
I filled that form, and through email, received an additional request to provide a video recording of YouTube API services usage, which I also provided. Reception was acknowledged through email too.

Since then, I've received emails to:

> Please complete and submit the requirements for resolving the violations provided in the previous email within the next seven (7) business days.

But I never got an email about said violations. Of course, I've replied to the emails, but never got an answer. We can't have that API access disabled, so I am attempting to reach a resolution by posting here too.

Can anyone help, or redirect to another touch point with the YouTube team?